# memory management and class member variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have the following code:

```
  @interface Reservation : RKObject {
    NSNumber * _uid;
    NSNumber * _did;
    NSNumber * _rid;
    NSString* _origin;
    NSString* _destination;
    NSString* _time_range;
    NSDate * _start_date;
    NSDate * _end_date;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * start_date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * end_date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * uid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * did;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * rid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * time_range;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * origin;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * destination;
@end

#import "Reservation.h"

@implementation Reservation
@synthesize time_range= _time_range;
@synthesize origin=_origin;
@synthesize destination=_destination;
@synthesize uid=_uid;
@synthesize did=_did;
@synthesize rid=_rid;
@synthesize start_date=_start_date;
@synthesize end_date=_end_date;


+ (NSDictionary*) elementToPropertyMappings {
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithKeysAndObjects:
            @"TIME_RANGE", @"time_range",
            @"ORIGIN_ADDRESS", @"origin",
            @"DESTINATION_ADDRESS", @"destination",
            @"UID", @"uid",
            @"DID", @"did",
            @"RID", @"rid",
            @"START_DATETIME", @"start_date",
            @"END_DATETIME", @"end_date",
            nil]; 
}


/*
+ (NSDictionary*)elementToRelationshipMappings {
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithKeysAndObjects:
            @"NSDate", @"start_date",
            @"NSDate", @"end_date",
            nil];
}
 */

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_start_date release];
    [_end_date release];
    [_uid release];
    [_did release];
    [_rid release];
    [_origin release];
    [_destination release];
    [_time_range release];
    //[_deal release];
    //[_route release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

@end

```
@interface ReservationViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, RKObjectLoaderDelegate>{
    Reservation * myres;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Reservation * myres;

#import "ReservationViewController.h"


@implementation ReservationViewController
@synthesize myres;

- (IBAction)makeReservation:(id)sender
{
    self.myres = [[[Reservation alloc] init] autorelease];  
    myres.start_date = [df dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [self.data objectForKey:@"date"], [self.data objectForKey:@"start_time"]]];
    myres.end_date = [df dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [self.data objectForKey:@"date"], [self.data objectForKey:@"end_time"]]];
    NSLog(@"date is %@", myres.start_date);
}

- (void)objectLoader: (RKObjectLoader*) objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)objects {
        Interval * res_int = [[Interval alloc] init];
        res_int.date1 = myres.start_date; //why is it null here
        res_int.date2 = myres.end_date; //why is it null here
        res_int.rid =  [[objects objectAtIndex:0] rid];
        [[LocationDictionary sharedLocationDictionary] addLocationtoDictionary:[self.data objectForKey:@"route"] withKey:res_int];
```

}

The question is why is `res_int.date1` null when I tried printing it out? When I print myres.start_date inside the method makeReservation, it prints appropriately Can someone explain this to me and how to fix it?

**UPDATE:**

I have done the following at my setter:

```
-(void) setStart_date:(NSDate *) boo
{
     NSAssert(boo != nil, @"why is this nil");
    _start_date = boo;    

}
```

at the end the stack trace I got is:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'why is this nil'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x019ac5a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01b00313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01964ef8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   Foundation                          0x014013bb -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
    4   Project                            0x00012d42 -[Reservation setStart_date:] + 194
    5   Foundation                          0x0137e5e5 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 285
    6   Project                           0x0004c7b3 -[RKObjectMapper updateModel:ifNewPropertyValue:forPropertyNamed:] + 172
    7   Project                            0x0004cd55 -[RKObjectMapper setPropertiesOfModel:fromElements:] + 754
    8   Project                            0x0004d8f3 -[RKObjectMapper updateModel:fromElements:] + 50
    9   Project                            0x0004bb7a -[RKObjectMapper mapObject:fromDictionary:] + 201
    10  Project                            0x0004ba42 -[RKObjectMapper mapObject:fromString:] + 148
    11  Project                            0x0004927b -[RKObjectLoader processLoadModelsInBackground:] + 537
    12  Foundation                          0x01370cf4 -[NSThread main] + 81
    13  Foundation                          0x01370c80 __NSThread__main__ + 1387
    14  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x931a085d _pthread_start + 345
    15  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x931a06e2 thread_start + 34
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Comment: -1 I don't see any global variables here.

Comment: myres is a global variable right

Comment: According to the code above `myres` is a class member variable in `ReservationViewController'. Therefore it's not global.

Comment: edited the title of the question, please upvote it again

Comment: Now it looks more a misunderstanding of RKObjectMapper than anything about memory management.

Comment: FWIW, your setter for `start_date` is incorrect. The `start_date` property is defined as `retain`. This means your setter needs to release the previous object and retain the new object. `[_start_date release]; _start_date = [boo retain];`

Answer (score 1):

What is the calling sequence of `makeReservation` (from the IBAction) and `objectLoader`? Is it possible that `objectLoader` is called before `makeReservation` so `myres` hasn't been initialized yet?

What is the interface definition for the `did` property of Reservation? Your line:

```
myres.did = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:[[[data objectForKey:@"discount"] did] intValue]];
```

If it defined as `(nonatomic, retain)` you may be retaining the NSNumber object without releasing it. If so, change the line to:

```
myres.did = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[[data objectForKey:@"discount"] did] intValue]];
```

You should also uncomment your line:

`//[res_int release]`

Comment: I did all your suggestions and makeReservation is called first before objectLoader... still it is null

Comment: there's a lot of stuff going on we can't see in this code sample. For example, have you checked that `myres.start_date != nil` in `objectLoader` after it is first assigned? `[df dateFromString:...]` could be failing also. I would start there and work your way forward testing all assumptions as you go. Add some `NSLog()` statements to output the values to the debugging console.

Comment: just tried doing a myres.start_date inside objectLoader and yes it is nil, but why?????

Comment: you need to keep debugging. so now you know that `[df dateFromString:...]` is failing. Break the function apart and check the values of the arguments. One or more of these is clearly invalid so somewhere along the line you are not setting something correctly. Again, I would start at the very beginning. E.g. where are the very first values assigned, check that it is working. Then go to the next step, etc. Eventually you will find the exact spot it breaks and then the "why" should become clear.

Comment: also, where are you allocating and setting `df`? I assume that it is an instance of NSDateFormatter. Try `[df dateFromString:@"REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_SAMPLE_DATE_STRING"]` and use a valid string you are expecting from your arguments. Does that work? Check each argument you are using to construct the date string. Are they correct? Etc etc. This is just standard debugging. You'll find the problem.

Comment: if I replace that df dateFromString with [NSDate date] the problem still persists.. check the comments I made on the other 2 posts. The issue is not with dateFormatter, for some reason start_date is set to nil after going to the objectLoader method, the other attributes of myres is not nil

Comment: if you are saying that in `objectLoader` you added the line `myres.start_date = [NSDate date]` and immediately checked the value of `myres.start_date` and it is nil then you have something wrong in the `Reservation` class. You're getting some good suggestions to help you debug this from me and others but you haven't posted enough of your code for us to see what's going on.

Comment: I am not saying in the objectLoader but in the makeReservation. I don't know what else you want to see in my code, the code above is everything where I used myres. The Reservation is just the plain normal class where everything is nonatomic, retain

Comment: what should I change that with? start_date? 
@synthesize start_date = start_date?

Comment: The iVar and property definition for `start_date` is fine, that's not the problem. A few comments ago I was asking you to verify that everything is working correctly only in `makeReservation`. Have you done that? Don't worry about `objectLoader` until you are 100% sure that myres is setup how you expect in `makeReservation`.

Comment: How can I verify that everything is working correctly only in objectLoader? It is not working properly and that is the issue now because start_date and end_date is nil at objectLoader. objectLoader is called directly after makeReservation.

Comment: Sorry, just changed my comment. I had the function names backwards. I do see below that you are saying that 'makeReservation' is working fine. If that's true, there aren't many other options. Your iVar/property definitions look right. Either `myres` is being modified in some part of your code we can't see or `objectLoader` is being called before `makeReservation`. I don't see other options.

Comment: Is RKObject a class defined by you? If so, can you please post its code? Also, can you put a log statement in the dealloc of reservation?

Comment: Why do you need the Interval as well? At this point I am not even setting Interval's date with myres.start_date?

Comment: reservation is autoreleased at this point, RKObject is a class from RestKit (a framework)

Comment: the original question related to `res_int.date1 == nil` after assignment. I wanted to confirm that the Interval class is setup correctly. If you are simply doing `NSLog(@"myres.start_date = %@", myres.start_date)` in `objectLoader` and it is nil then I'm back to `objectLoader` being called first or some other method changing the value of `myres`. How have you verified this is not the case?

Comment: objectLoader is not called first and quite sure that no other method changes the value of myres. If it were called first, the value of myres.did would be nil as well, in this case it is not nil

Comment: Well, there is nothing obviously wrong with the code you posted so I don't know what else to tell you. Your iVars and properties are correct. Whatever the problem is, it's in something you haven't shared, unintentional as it may be.

Answer (score 0):

in your makeReservation method, try the following:

```
self.myres = [[[Reservation alloc] init] autorelease];
```

This will retain the Reservation object.

Edit: XJones is right. Editing the line of code.

Comment: Actually, it's good practice to name your variables something other than the name of your property to avoid confusion.  So something like @property (nonatomic, retain) Reservation *myres; @synthesize myres = _myres;

Comment: this is wrong. the property `myres` is defined as retain so your line of code should be `self.myres = [[[Reservation alloc] init] autorelease]` otherwise the instance will be retained twice (once by the alloc and again by the `myres` property setter). Or, just leave it the way you have it. You are allocating myres into the iVar directly so it's retained properly already. I do agree with @Micah Hainline regarding naming.

Comment: Are you sure that the dateFromString in makeReservation is giving you correct date?

Comment: I printed out myres.start_date in the makeReservation function and it prints out the date.. when I print myres.start_date in the objectLoader method it is nil

Comment: Is myres nil in objectLoader or is just the start_date nil? If its just start_date nil, I am not sure why the value is not being retained since you did confirm below that it is a property with 'retain'.

Comment: yes just the start_date is nil, the other attributes of my_res such as did is not nil.. tried printing it out

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely in `Reservation.h`.

Make sure you the property statement for your dates are as follow:

```
@property (non-atomic, retain) NSDate *start_date;
@property (non-atomic, retain) NSDate *end_date;
```

The import attribute here is **retain**.

Comment: and the class Interval has the same for the date1 & date2 property?

Comment: Well I would sprinkle some NSLog in makeReservation method to see what is null.  Are use NSAssert. For example: `NSLog(@"Date Formatter: %@", df);`, `NSLog(@"Data Date: %@", [self.data objectForKey:@"date"]);`, etc

Comment: as I edited the question above... myres.start_date is not null at makeReservation

Comment: And when you reach objectLoader method, are you sure `myres != nil`?

Comment: myres is not nil but myres.start_date is nil... now the question is why

Comment: Well I would override the setter method for start_date in your `Reservation.m` to log the date to console with `NSLog` or use `NSAssert` to check for `nil`. Somewhere in your code is setting it to nil.

Comment: so do a method -(void)setDate1:(NSDate *) date? Can I keep the @synthesize date1?

Comment: Your property is start_date so it would be: `- (void)setStart_date:(NSDate *)date`

Comment: ok I can see that it is actually setting the start_date to nil

Comment: You should use `NSAsset(date != nil, @"why is this nil");' and when it break, so a stack trace to see where it's getting set after the makeReservation method is called.

Comment: where should I do this? inside the setter?

Comment: Yes, inside the setter because you want to know when it gets set to nil.

Comment: Looking at your stack trace, the methods below setStart_date, are those call after you set the start_date initially?