# Date formatter is not working in iOS6, but working perfectly in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

Processing a date string in the format: `June 12, 2014 - 19:35:51 UTC`.

```
NSString * dateStr = @"June 12, 2014 - 19:35:51 UTC";
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy - HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *startTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString: dateStr];
```

This works perfectly in iOS7, not in iOS6 getting `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the locale like this:

```
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
```

[See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14890612/1270148)