# Why do I need to set locale on NSDateFormatter when using "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, datetime, nsdateformatter

I had a weird issue today, I have the following code:

```
#define kApiDateFormat @"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"

...
+ (NSDate*)dateWithApiFormatString:(NSString*)dateString {

  NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormat setDateFormat:kApiDateFormat];
  return [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];

}
```

The date i'm trying to format is `12/29/2014 12:00:00 AM` and my device's locale is `es_CL`, searching on the internet [I've found a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638416/datefromstring-always-returns-null-with-dateformatter), I needed to set the locale of the dateFormatter to `en_US` like this:

```
[dateFormat setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
```

So my question is the following... WHY?, I couldn't find any information explaining why I couldn't parse the date string to a date using my device's locale.

Thanks

Comment: `"AM"` and `"PM"` are not necessarily represented the same in every locale.

Comment: [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html). Read it all, a short quote only for reference: "On iOS, the user can override the default AM/PM versus 24-hour time setting (via Settings > General > Date & Time > 24-Hour Time), which causes NSDateFormatter to rewrite the format string you set, which can cause your time parsing to fail."

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613110/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-the-nsdateformatter-locale-feature